# QtCore installation for ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, torch

I have been trying to install torch but i'm getting the following error when I run ./install.sh

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:664 (message):
  Could NOT find QtCore.  Check
  /home/name/torch/exe/qtlua/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log for more
  details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:38 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/name/torch/exe/qtlua/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Error: Build error: Failed building.

Missing dependencies for qttorch:
qtlua >= 1.0
```

I have already tried installing QtCore using

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core
```

but still, I'm getting an error:

```
Could NOT find QtCore
```

as shown above. Why is this and how can I fix this?

Steps I followed for installation:
http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_

EDIT (SOLVED):
I had to install qt4-dev-tools also using

```
apt-get install qt4-dev-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by replace find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED) by find_package(Qt5Widgets) in all my CMakeList.txt.

[Detecting Qt5 with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163381/detecting-qt5-with-cmake)