# CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH for Qt5

Tags: linux, qt, cmake, qt5

I want to compile [this](https://github.com/KDE/kwin) which requires `Qt` 5.14 and I have Qt 5.12 installed from my linux repository.I just compiled Qt from source and installed it in `/usr/local/Qt-6.0.0/`(default location).
But CMake prints the following error although I've added `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/Qt-6.0.0/include")` and/or `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/Qt-6.0.0/")` :

```
The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.12.8
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.12.8
```

Comment: you have to point to the location where the configuration files are located.                                     ex: Qt5_DIR="/Users/bob/Qt/5.12.7/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5"                                                               you can use `Qt5_DIR` or `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, both should work.

Comment: @cppiscute In my case , QT5_DIR worked.Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cmake does not find qt 5.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722329/cmake-does-not-find-qt-5-1-1)

Comment: @squareskittles QT5_DIR was enough.The important part is that it should point to the "Qt_installation/lib/cmake/Qt5/" directory which contains some modules to help CMake find the Qt libraries.

Comment: This [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169447/3987854) also touches on this topic, specifically mentioning the use of `Qt5_DIR`.

Comment: @squareskittles You're right.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Since it has solved your problem, I have added it as an answer please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it has solved your question, I am just going to put it as an answer here. I will improve this section more in detail later.

If you are using cmake use `find_package` to find the package and then link to your
binary in later stage.

```
In order for find_package to be successful, Qt 5 must be found below the
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, or the Qt5_DIR must be set in the CMake cache to the 
location   of the Qt5Config.cmake file. The easiest way to use CMake is to set the
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variable to the install prefix of Qt 5.
```

If you just want to find the Qt modules then just set the `Qt5_DIR`
`ex: Qt5_DIR="/Users/bob/Qt/5.12.7/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5"`

when building with `CMake` you can use Qt5_DIR or CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, both should work.

More explanation about building with CMake can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/cmake-manual.html)